# Using if-let with trailing closure

Tags: swift, ios8, closures

I have a function, for example:

```
func myFunction(aString: String, aClosure: (intArg: Int) -> (Void)) -> String? {
    aClosure(intArg: 1)
    return aString
}
```

I've kept it intentionally simple to better express my questions. I have two questions. First, is there a better way to use this function with a trailing closure than:

```
if let newString = (myFunction("hello world") {
    (intArg: Int) -> Void in
        println("Do nothing")
    }) {
    println(newString)    
}
```

I don't like having to place those extra parentheses around the function call.

My second question -- why is "Do nothing" not printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do the closure inline, I find going back to putting the trailing closure *inside* the function parentheses is better than wrapping the whole function + closure in parenthesis.

So:

```
if let newString = myFunction("hello world", { _->() in println("Do nothing") }) {
    println(newString)
}
```

instead of:

```
if let newString = (myFunction("hello world") { _->() in println("Do nothing") }) {
    println(newString)
}
```

`Do nothing` is printed just fine if I paste your code into a playground – though only in the timeline (cmd-opt-enter), not in the right-hand margin.

Answer (score 1):

I manipulated it and did it in the original fashion and it worked in my project printing do nothing, but it still showed the (0 elements) in sandbox. But when i check the console output in sandbox it does show up:

[image]

```
if let newString = myFunction("hello world", {
    (intArg: Int) -> Void in
    println("Do nothing")
}) {
    println(newString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is use a local function or closure that is defined right above of `if-let` part. The code:

```
// the local function
func completion(intArg: Int) {
    println("Do nothing")
}

// or closure

let completion: Int -> () = {_ in println("Do nothing")}

if let newString = myFunction("hello world", completion) {
    println(newString)
}
```

> My second question -- why is "Do nothing" not printed?

Maybe you are not calling `completion` inside `myFunction`